# contractive property

Tags: general-topology

A topological property $\mathcal{R}$ is contractive if $(X,\tau)$ has property $\mathcal{R}$ and if $\tau^{\prime} \subset \tau$,
then (A, $\tau^{\prime}$) has property $\mathcal{R}$.

A topological space is $T_B$ if each compact subset  is closed.

A topological space is called a US-space provided that each convergent sequence has a unique limit.

A topological space is called a C- C-space provided that  the  compact subsets  are precisely the closed sets.

> Is property C-C , US contractive,  hereditary?
>
> Is property $T_B$  contractive?

Answer (score 1):

The properties $C$-$C$, $US$, and $T_B$ are clearly not contractive. Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $[0,1]$ and $\tau'$ the cofinite topology; then $\langle[0,1],\tau\rangle$, being compact Hausdorff, has all three of these properties, and $\tau'\subseteq\tau$, but $\langle[0,1],\tau'\rangle$ has none of them.

The $US$ property is clearly hereditary: if $Y\subseteq X$, and $\sigma$ is a sequence in $Y$ that converges to distinct points $u$ and $v$ of $Y$, then $\sigma$ converges to both $u$ and $v$ in $X$ as well, so if $Y$ is not $US$, $X$ is also not $US$.

The $C$-$C$ property is not hereditary: $[0,1]$ with the usual topology is compact Hausdorff and therefore $C$-$C$, and its subspace $(0,1)$ is not $C$-$C$, since $(0,1)$ is a closed set in $(0,1)$ that is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

If a space $(X,\tau)$ is $T_B$, US or C-C, then all finite sets are closed in such a space.

This means that taking for $\tau'$ the co-finite topology on $X$, and assuming that $X$ is infinite (or we have a finite discrete space) we have in all cases $\tau' \subset \tau$, but $(X,\tau')$ itself is not C-C (any set is compact, only finite sets are closed), US (all sequences with all points different converge to all points) nor $T_B$ (see before).

So none are contractive, for infinite $X$.